# Find first number anywhere after a specific pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to identify a number that occurs after a certain substring in R.

For example:

```
sa <- "100 dollars 200"
```

In the above string, to find the number that appears after the word `dollar`, I execute the below code:

```
str_match_all(sa,"(?<=dollars )\\d+")
```

and I get the below outcome:

```
  [[1]]
     [,1] 
[1,] "200"
```

However, when I use the following input:

```
sa <- "100 dollars for 200 pesos"
```

I fail terribly to get the output as `200`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is to simply use `gsub()` to get the number you want. More specifically, you can define a pattern that will search for the first number that follows the word 'dollars'.

```
# define the pattern
pat <- "^.*dollars.*?([0-9]+).*"

# example 1
str <- "100 dollars for 200 pesos"
gsub(pat, "\\1", str)
[1] "200"

# example 2
str <- " 100, actually 100.12 dollars for 200 pesos or 1000 dimes"
gsub(pat, "\\1", str)
[1] "200"
```

To better explain the pattern:

```
^        >> from the beginning of the string...
.*       >> every character till... 
dollars  >> the substring 'dollars'...
.*?      >> and than any character until the first...
([0-9]+) >> number of any length, that is selected as group...
.*       >> and then everything else
```

when this pattern is matched, `gsub()` replaces it with the number selected as group, that means the first number after 'dollars'.

Comment: Thank you Damiano. can you please explain how is .* are working in the code as this looks tricky for me.

Comment: I expanded the answer to include a better description of what the elements in the pattern mean. I hope this may be useful...

Comment: Nice answer. unfortunately this does not work if the number is a decimal. e.g. dollars 200.5

Answer (score 1):

You may *capture* the digits after 0 or more non-digits. `The`str_match`function differs from the`str_extract` in this aspect, it preserves all the capturing group values.

```
> sa<-"100 dollars for 200 pesos"
> str_match_all(sa,"dollars\\D*(\\d+)")
[[1]]
     [,1]              [,2] 
[1,] "dollars for 200" "200"
```

Just use the values in the second column.

**Pattern details**

- `dollars` - matches a `dollars` substring
- `\\D*` - zero or more chars other than digits (it also matches whitespaces)
- `(\\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.

To just extract the `200` value, you may use `regmatches/regexpr`:

```
sa<-c("100 dollars for 200 pesos", "100 dollars 200 pesos")
regmatches(sa, regexpr("dollars\\D*\\K\\d+", sa, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "200" "200"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/QLan3e).

**Details**

- `dollars` - a substring
- `\\D*` - any 0+ chars other than digits
- `\\K` - match reset operator
- `\\d+` - 1 or more digits.

The same pattern with `.*` as prefix/suffix can be used with `sub` (no need for a `gsub` since we only need one search and replace operation:

```
sa<-c("100 dollars for 200 pesos", "100 dollars 200 pesos")
sub(".*dollars\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1", sa)
## => [1] "200" "200"
```

See [yet another demo](https://ideone.com/OKsehT)

Comment: Though Damiano's logic is apt for the example i provided, am more keen to know with the given approach, how to get 200 in the out put

Comment: @Santosh Then you may use `regmatches(sa, regexpr("dollars\\D*\\K\\d+", sa, perl=TRUE))`